# OPENQUERY in SQL Server shows error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using linked server below query but it shows an error. Am I missing any quotes? Can anybody help me?

```
DECLARE @fromdt DATETIME = '2018-04-07';
DECLARE @EndDate1 DATETIME = '2018-04-07';

SELECT * 
FROM OPENQUERY(TIMEV,
               'SELECT REPLACE(LTRIM(REPLACE(badgenumber,"0"," "))," ","0") badgenumber, checktime as dt
                FROM checkinout a 
                JOIN USERINFO c ON c.userid = a.userid  
                WHERE checktime >= '''''+CONVERT(CHAR(10), @fromdt, 120)+'''''  AND ''''' + CONVERT(CHAR(10), @EndDate1, 120) + ''''' ')
```

Comment: You are using double quotes where single quotes are preferable.

Comment: kindly clear that.. i cant find that..

Comment: You must write the error Msg in your question, it help users to help you, always try to provide enough information to work with.

Comment: It shows error:Incorrect syntax near '+'.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something more like this:

```
Select * 
from openquery(TIMEV, '
SELECT REPLACE(LTRIM(REPLACE(badgenumber, ''0'', '' '')), '' '', ''0'') badgenumber,checktime as dt
FROM checkinout a JOIN
     USERINFO c 
     ON c.userid = a.userid  
WHERE checktime >= CAST(''' + @fromdt + ''' as date)  AND CAST(''' + @EndDate1 + ''' as date)
';
```

Comment: Shows error:Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ');